# HTML Error 500 when I including autoloader

Tags: php, spl-autoloader

This is my code.
Index.php

```
define('_PATH', __DIR__ . '/');
require_once('libs/classloader.php');
echo 'test';
```

Classloader.php

```
function ClassLoader($className)
  {
    if(file_exists(__DIR__ '/class.'. strtolower($className) . '.php'))
    {
      require_once(__DIR__ '/class.'. strtolower($className) . '.php');
    }
    else {
      echo 'ERROR: '. $className;
    }
  }

  spl_autoload_register('ClassLoader');
```

I see only error 500 in my browser. PHP version is 5.4 and server is LiteSpeed.

Comment: `500` indicates internal server error. I believe LiteSpeed also has error log that you can check.

Comment: What does your PHP error log report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this small change should helps:

```
function ClassLoader($className)
{
    if(file_exists(__DIR__ .'/class.'. strtolower($className) . '.php'))
    //if(file_exists(__DIR__ '/class.'. strtolower($className) . '.php'))
    {
      require_once(__DIR__ .'/class.'. strtolower($className) . '.php');
      //require_once(__DIR__ '/class.'. strtolower($className) . '.php');
    }
    else {
      echo 'ERROR: '. $className;
    }
}

spl_autoload_register('ClassLoader');
```

Comment: Thanks. I noticed that it does not show me the error on the page (and logs), it only displays an error 500. How to fix it? display_errors turned on and used the function error_reporting ().

Comment: I use xdebug extension
    sudo apt-get install php5-xdebug
It shows full stacktrace, also you can check this link to see how to enabe startup errors.

http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-startup-errors